# Crystal Report create separate report pages based on field value change

Tags: crystal-reports

Looking for some advice related to data grouping and printing in Crystal Reports.

I'm working with an order confirmation form. Ideally I would create separate report pages based on a specific field value change for the 'warehouse' field. So, if any given line on an order comes from warehouse A, it prints together. Then we'd get a page break, and we'd see the form repeat for any lines coming from warehouse B.

I've inserted a new group for "warehouse" and configured the group as 'New Page Before.' But when I attempt to print I'm getting an error related to "There must be a group that matches this field". So there must be some pre-existing grouping that I'm not considering. I'm hopeful I can figure this out.

I am interested to get thoughts on overall design, and if the grouping approach I am trying to take is even the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your report you probably have a formula such as:

Sum({some_value}, {some_field})

where the {some_field} used to be -- but is no longer -- grouped upon.

Fix that expression to set the desired aggregation level (the 2nd argument) to a field you are actually grouping on.